# What to do to avoid bootstrap use hiding other function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created page which have left div portion for displaying dashboard and rightside div portion for displaying some icons. once icon is clicked, it should display popup . I used bootstrap for this. It works fine but the problem is, left side div portion is not visible. Anyone guide me that what would be an issue here and how to resolve it?

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="background: #e5e5e5; overflow: hidden;">
                <div id="left_DB" align="left"
                    style="float: left;  height: 99%; overflow: auto; position: relative;top:1%;"
                    class="left_panel"> Dashboard goes here </div>
                <div id="sideFilters" align="right"
                    style="float: right; width: 50px; background-color: #191919; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 32px;">
                    <div class="rightside" id="ddldiv" style="overflow:hidden;">

                    <a data-toggle="#selectModal" data-target="#modal">
                        <img src="../images/profile.png" height='25' width='25' draggable="false" id="sddl">
                    </a>

                </div>

                    <div class="rightside">
                        <a href="#export" id="exportButton" title="Export"
                            draggable="false"><img src="../images/reports/export.png"
                            width="20" ; draggable="false" id="exportImg"
                            onclick="exportImgDoc();svgToCanvas();" /> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 </div>


<!-- To create customer selection modal pop up when clicking icon on right side -->
        <div class="modal" id="selectModal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Select value </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                        <form> 
                            <div class="form-group"> 

                                <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                    <label for="Cvalue" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important">Value </label>
                            </td>
                        <td style="width: 75%" id="SelectTd"><div style="width: 130px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important;">
                                <select class="form-control" id="cValue" title="Value" ></select>
                            </div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Post what you've tried so far. That will help people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the modal window is hiding(the semi transparent background) the leftbox?

Then try settings a high `z-index` value for the left div element which you want to make appear.

```
z-index: 99999;
```

Example:

[image]

Here, when I set a higher `z-index` for the left box in the above example page, it got popped out from the semi transparent background of the modal window!

Hope it helps. Otherwise, please give us some more details to better understand your problem.

Comment: Thnka you for your response Akhilesh. The issue still exists.

Comment: Kindly give us the screenshot of the issue that you are facing now, to better understand it.

Comment: Let me try to understand my problem. The page is moreover like screenshot above. Build a better website part contains icons. and Modal plugin page contains dashboard. while clicking image on the right side, it displays popup in the modal plugin page. But after that dashboard page doesn't visible

Comment: After adding bootstrp stuff, dashboard part is not visible...I am completely new for coding. It would be great if it helps

Comment: I use Greenshot for screen capturing: http://getgreenshot.org/  Or you can use Lightshot: https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html